# How to align absolute positioned sections with height: auto

Tags: css

I am building a website with different sections with absolute positioning, one of the sections has a `height: auto`, I was trying to align them by setting up a `top: x vh;` but it didn't work since there is a `height:auto` value.

These are the sections:

```
    #navbar{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:10vh;
  top:0;
  left:0;
   }
    #greeting{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:90vh;
  top:10vh;
  left:0;
}
    #projects{
  width:100%;
  min-height:90vh;
  height:auto;

  position:absolute;
  top:100vh;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

I want to add a new section after projects but I couldn't set the top value.

https://codepen.io/Kairkan/pen/LYyoVRX?editors=1100
this is my full code on codepen

HTML

```
<section id="contact">
   <h1 id="contact-h1">Let's work together</h1>
   <h3 id="contact-h3">How do you take your coffee?</h3>
</section>
```

/////
CSS

```
#contact{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;

  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;

  background-color: #393A42;
}
```

This is the subsequent section. But it stacks on the top of the page because I couldn't set the `top:`  value

Comment: Hello. Share a full code snippet with us.

Comment: Can you provide an image of what do you want and what are you getting instead??

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use absolute positioning.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using absolute positioning since it looks as though the sections should follow on from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset the `margin` property in the body section as follows:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

then you can remove `position: absolute`, `top`, and `left`.Then just position your sections one by one as follows:

```
#greeting {
  margin-top: 10vh;
  height:90vh;
  // ... other styles
}

#projects{
  min-height:90vh;
  // ... other styles
}

#contact {
  min-height: 90vh;
  background: lightblue;
  // ... other styles
}
```

ps. 1 You don't have to use `width: 100%` on `div` and other block elements because that makes no sense. [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

> A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).

ps. 2 Avoid styling with IDs. Use classes instead. [see](https://dev.to/clairecodes/reasons-not-to-use-ids-in-css-4ni4)